# How to store users transactions history on database and how to show the transaction history whenever a user wants to view their transactions

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I’ve a problem that I don’t seem to find on the internet. I was trying to create a website where users transaction histories  are saved on the database. Let’s say after a new user signs up and login and then starts to buy or sell stuff from the site, their past transactions should be saved in the database, so whenever they want to view their transaction it will show them their transactions histories. If they  have 1, 3 , 12 or more  transactions history it will show them everything. My problem now is I don’t know how to do it or even start. It should be able to look a table for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Please make one more table with required transaction columns with post-fix of tablename_history. Use primary key with Auto increment for reference. i.e history_id.
But important thing is that you need to make separate transaction to Insert and Update Query to avoid performance issue.